# How to prevent an android device from entering sleep (via adb command shell)

Tags: android, adb, sleep, suspend

I am working on an embedded board with android on it. Unfortunately I cannot use the display as I dont have a supporting display device (LVDS display).

### Problem :

Everytime i bootup the device, the device goes into sleep after some time.

```
Restarting tasks ... done.
PM: suspend exit 1970-01-01 00:35:30.797352016 UTC
PM: suspend entry 1970-01-01 00:35:30.905410683 UTC
PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
```

How can i avoid it from shell prompt? I am able to login to shell through serial port.

I cannot modify the settings as i dont have access to display.

Comment: $ adb shell svc power stayon true Taken [from](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27681288/2299040)

Comment: @SahilManchanda Pls make it as answer. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`$ adb shell svc power stayon true`

Comment: Is this a persistent setting? Or is it something that need to be called after every reboot / power off?

Comment: @W.M. i think it's not persistent. never tried it after reboot.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/svc/src/com/android/commands/svc/PowerCommand.java

According to the above this is the equivalent of Setting keep awake while plugged in